# Analysis of the reflection in metal

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics

In order to solve the reflexion in a material with a complex index the solution I've found on textbooks is to define $\hat{n}\cos{\phi}:=a+bi$ where $\hat{n}=n_r+n_ii$ is the complex index and then solve the system

$$a^2-b^2=n_r^2 - n_i^2 -n^2\sin^2(\phi)$$

$$ab=n_rn_i$$

Then, with the complex expression for $\hat{n}\cos{\phi}$ you could determine the $r_\parallel$ and $r_\perp$ coefficients.

However, to solve this, I've attempted simplifying the problem by solving for the complex expression for $\cos \phi '$.

To do this, by using Snells law and Pythagoras law I get the expression'

$$\cos \phi '= \sqrt{1-(\frac{n}{\hat{n}}\sin \phi )^2 }$$

Now, defining $\sqrt{z}=\pm \sqrt{|z|}e^{i\phi/2}$ I can get the complex expression for the cosine. Each of the two solutions for the square mathematically represents an offset of $\pi$ in the complex phase.

The problem with this is that I don't know when I should choose the positive or the negative solutions for the complex module of the cosine.

Answer (score 0):

Why are using a law of refraction (snell's law) for reflection in metals?

[image]

You can not compute reflections in metal without taking into consideration of wavelength.

Refractive index of metals varies largely for different wavelengths. Different metal absorbs different wavelength that also give metals its color.

The refractive index for plastic tends to decrease with increasing wavelength wheras RI of metals increase with increasing wavelength.